# How to input numbers and variables in a Recursion method

Tags: java, recursion, input

So I'm wondering how you're suppsoed to input information from the user end for example if the code where something like this

```
public static int mystery(String str)
{
    if (str.length() == 1) return 0;
    else
    {
        if (str.substring(0,1).equals("y")) return 1 +
                           mystery(str.substring(1));
        else return mystery(str.substring(1));
    }
}
```

And I had to plug in different letters from the user end how would I do that?
A better way to explain it is if I'm given this code and had to put in "xyzxyxy" how would I plug it in from the user end.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with `plug in different letters from the user end`? Do you mean pass another String but "y" into the method?

Comment: It seems that you need to get a user entered string (using `Scanner` or another suitable class) and then **pass** it to your method.

Comment: To test different strings of letters with the same code @ Alexander

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? It will enable you to try as many words as you like.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        System.out.println(mystery(scanner.next()));
    }
}
```

By the way, if your method is supposed to count the number of `y`s in the `String` it should be

```
if (str.length() == 0) return 0;
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant but how would it look like with my original code in there?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do that because `mystery` is recursive. If you want to use recursion you'd need 2 different methods.